# Using variables with translate filter in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am working on an AngularJs project and I am using the translate filter the following way:

```
<h2>{{'This is my text' | translate}}</h2>
```

It works fine, but I would like to be able to use variables in my translations. Here is what I have tried:

In the controller:

```
vm.text = "This {{toReplace}} is a variable.";
vm.myVariable = "random value";
```

In the html:

```
<h2>{{vm.text | translate:'{ toReplace: vm.myVariable }'}}</h2>
```

It doesn't replace {{toReplace}} with the content of myVariable. Instead, the  page displays "This {{toReplace}} is a variable."

What should I do to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that has worked for me, considering 'myVariable' is a variable defined in my controller:

```
<h2 data-translate>This {{vm.myVariable}} is a variable</h2>
```

The tricky part is that, just like when using the translate filter, the text in the element is not the text being displayed, but the ID of the element to translate. In the translation files (po), you will have to have an element with the ID 'This {{vm.myVariable}} is a variable', including the name of the variable. If you need to display the same text but with data coming from a different variable, you would have to declare a different translation with its own ID, even though only the variable part of the text is different.

For exemple, this would have to be a different entry in the translation files:

```
<h2 data-translate>This {{vm.myVariable2}} is a variable</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the directive rather than the filter ? Something like this :

```
<h2 translate="vm.text" translate-values={'toReplace':vm.myVariable}"></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

`vm.text` must contain a valid translate key, which you should define in your language files. The value of the translate key will be `"This {{toReplace}} is a variable."`. Then your HTML should render correctly.

If you just want to render this text without internationalization support, you could just do this:

```
<h2>This {{vm.toReplace}} is a variable.</h2>
```